# Sematice Issue Property "customUserAgent" not found on object type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I am new to objective c but I have an app I was compiling and it's throwing errors on xcode 6. Any time I click archive the build fails and points to wkWebview.customUserAgent saying that Property not found on object type customUserAgent is not found on type WKWebview. I have combed the web in search of solutions but I couldn't find. I am guessing that customUserAgent was not explicitly defined and I don't simply don't know how to. I'll appreciate any pointer.

```js
  // re-create WKWebView, since we need to update configuration
    WKWebView* wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.engineWebView.frame configuration:configuration];
    wkWebView.UIDelegate = self.uiDelegate;
    self.engineWebView = wkWebView;

    if (IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"9.0") && [self.viewController isKindOfClass:[CDVViewController class]]) {
        wkWebView.customUserAgent = ((CDVViewController*) self.viewController).userAgent;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you are calling property that is defined in latest version of OS. As you mentioned you are using Xcode 6, try this code with Xcode 7+. Check Frameworks-> WebKit.framework-> Headers-> WKWebView.h-> Line 229

> /*! @abstract The custom user agent string or nil if no custom user
>   agent string has been set.
>   */ @property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *customUserAgent API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.11), ios(9.0));

Comment: Thanks santak, but what if updating xcode is not an option, any way around that?